# Rails onChange form submit does not submit value

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I am trying to create a simple form with a hidden field and select_tag. I want this form to be submitted onChange. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<%= form_for :model, :multipart => true, :remote => true, :url => target_url do |f| %><br>
      <% @array.each do |r| %><br>
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="list block">
            <%= image_tag(r.image_url(:sm_thumb)) if r.try(:images).try(:first) %><br>
            <%= r.child.try(:name) %><br>
            <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value =>  r.id %><br>
            <%= select_tag 'interested_field', options_from_collection_for_select(@array_of_choices, 'id', 'first_name'), :prompt => 'Some Message', :onChange=>"this.form.submit()" if @appropriate? %><br>
          </li>  
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

It works for most part, as in I am able to submit the form onChange, the problem though is sometime (and it has been random) the value for the select box is not set in the params that are sent to the controller. So if a user makes a selection, the form gets submitted with a blank value in interested_field as in  `params[:interested_field] = ''` despite the fact that the user is selecting a value. I can't figure out for the life of me, why this might be happening. Any input is much appreciated.

I am using rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Have you tried `javascript:this.form.submit()` ?

Comment: Yes, that does not work either.

Comment: add a validation in the model, restricting blank value.

Comment: I am using select_tag because the form does not modify the model. I have logic in the controller to reject blank params and show an error message, but its still bad user experience. Is there any reason for it being this way? Is there a better way to do this, that delivers a more consistent user experience?

Comment: Do you use [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)?

Comment: No I do not use Turbolinks. I have been looking at it for the past week or so, can you explain how you think it would help me here, from what I understand my issue is completely unrelated to what turbolinks does, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it unobtrusively. You'll need the ID of the form, for now `#new_model`. Add this to your javascript for the page:

```
var modelForm = $("#new_model");
modelForm.find("select").change(function() {
   if( $(this).val() ) modelForm.submit();
});
```

This will at least have it not submit if there is no value. Its strange that you enumerate a bunch of selects for the same field though...